# Winter Bash 2013/2014: Misalignment of the hat boxes due to incomplete CSS rule set

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash-2013, winter-bash-2014

### Update (2014):

The [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) site has the same problem as the site last year.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Winterbash 2014 Misalignment]

**What’s the problem?**

This CSS rule declaration targets only **the 5th element** in there:

```
.box:nth-child(5) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Instead, the margin of **every 5th box** should be removed:

```
.box:nth-child(5n+1) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

### Last years question:

On the [Winter Bash 2013 site](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), the box for *Ho Ho Ho* has its `margin-right` reset. Therefor the *Do the Swim!* is not aligned to the right, like the other boxes are.

**Winter Bash 2013:**

[image: Winterbash 2013 Misalignment]

Comment: I [see it](http://i.imgur.com/iuyl5ZV.png) just fine. What browser/OS do you use? Can you post a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: Seem just fine here. What browser/OS you have?

Comment: @AmalMurali Its hard to notice, but the discrepancy _is_ there, even in your picture.

Comment: Just hit the dev tools and check the _Ho Ho Ho_ box, the applied css rule is there. This will be there, no matter what browser you're using (if it supports `nth-child`). Thanks to Lance Roberts, he made a screenshot. You can see it.

Comment: Unless they serve different stylesheet for different browsers. I see it too (Chrome and IE11, Win8.1).

Comment: @3ventic Well, that's right. I've checked in latest Firefox and IE, same thing there.

Comment: On almost all the boxes for the hats, (_ha, hatboxes_), the left margin is 0 and the right margin is 12. On the "Ho Ho Ho" box, both margins are 0.

Comment: Well, this will be nullified anyway in couple of days so guess it's not worth the time to fix it. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard The fix is super easy (see my question). Assuming this or a similar layout will be used next year, why not fix it now?

Comment: @kleinfreund fixing production code requires more time than just replacing code... consider just the time to make sure it doesn't break anything else. The design this year is totally different from last year so most likely next year it will also be different. All in all, [meh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meh). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, it's okay. Should've noticed it earlier. ;) Appart from that: Changing the CSS rule as suggesting won't break anything on that page. Some CSS wizard can confirm this. :p

Comment: @kleinfreund well, too bad I'm just a Shadow wizard not CSS wizard. :D

Comment: Voted to reopen.