# Unbreakable long display name overflows into the hats territory

Tags: bug, status-declined, display-names, winter-bash-2014

Reporting a bug before it actually happens:

> [image]

When [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531954/4#winter-bash) will collect more than 18 hats, the display name would invade into the hats region.

Need to stop this invasion! :)

Comment: Why is this "status-declined"?

Comment: @Sam because Josh (Shog9) decided it's not breaking anything thus not worthy of being fixed.

Comment: @Sam Shog didn't get notification for your comment, better repost the comment on his answer.

Comment: 10-4 thanks, deleting and reposting

Answer (score 4):

No it won't:

[image]

Comment: OK, but it's still quite ugly. Won't it be better to hide the overflow like it's already done in many other places? (worth to mention that "ordinary" long names are nicely wrapped, into several lines)

Comment: Oh, *not being ugly* is a criteria now? Then I'm afraid there's no choice but to just rename the user.

Comment: Not sure I get you... all it takes is trivial CSS change. (setting a fixed width and `overflow: hidden;` rule)

Comment: Anyone else thinking "That's a weird-looking version of Space Invaders" when seeing that screenshot? No? Just me?   Okay.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Don't worry, the devs have it on their list to fix. ETA is 5th Jan...

Comment: @James: And then they introduce a similar bug for winterbash 2015? Or will they just close it as non-repro at that time?

Comment: I understand why priority for this may be low (an edge case on a seasonal page) but it seems that there should at least be a solution in place to ensure that the same flaw doesn't make it into production pages of the future. If the user is required to change the format of their name to enjoy the full potential of this view (& any others that share the same behavior) why not prevent them from having the name in the first place? Or create a global style to handle users with super long names? Perhaps much easier said then done.

Comment: @Bart both, they did it already [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214230/winter-bash-2013-2014-misalignment-of-the-hat-boxes-due-to-incomplete-css-rule). (see the revisions)