# If a moderator has a long name, the diamond gets truncated too

Tags: bug, design, truncation

If a moderator’s name is displayed next to a question or answer he authored and this name is sufficiently long to be truncated, the diamond gets truncated as well. Thus cannot immediately tell whether he is a moderator. This is particularly confusing on Meta where the diamond often makes a statement official.

[An example:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245505/255554)

> [image: Who is this guy and what are his qualifications on long usernames?]

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this still happen? I haven't noticed this recently.

Comment: @V2Blast: See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been solved at some point in the last years:

[image: Example of me using a long username]

Note that the username above uses the maximum number of characters. (Maybe CMs can override this though.)